# Linux search text string from .bz2 files recursively in subdirectories

Tags: linux, recursion, grep, bzip2

I have a case where multiple .bz2 files are situated in subdirectories. And I want to search for a text, from all files, using bzcat and grep command linux commands.

I am able to search one-one file by using the following command:

```
bzcat <filename.bz2> | grep -ia 'text string' | less
```

But I now I need to do the above for all files in subdirectories.

Comment: h try this bzcat <filename.bz2> | grep -ira 'text string' | less

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `bzgrep` instead of `bzcat` and `grep`. This is faster.

To grep recursively in a directory tree use `find`:

```
find -type f -name '*.bz2' -execdir bzgrep "pattern" {} \;
```

`find` is searching recursively for all files with the `*.bz2` extension and applies the command specified with `-execdir` to them.

Comment: Good one! Didn't know about bzgrep, so I am deleting my approach.

Comment: I just knowed about `zgrep`, so I tried `man bzgrep`. thx! :)

Comment: Thanks hek2mgl, I am running the command and will let you know of the result. The files I am searching from are too big.

Comment: Just to confirm something. Do I put my search text string in "pattern", replacing pattern with my string?

Comment: @user3041655 yes. replace pattern with your actual grep pattern

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to less(view) the result, how do I modify the command? Because bzgrep is not installed in my server, I had to replace it with bzcat. When running the modified command, it ran until the end by never showed any matching string. And I know the string is in the file.

Comment: This is the comand: `find -type -file -name 'SystemOut.log.bz2' execdir bzcat "62123456" {} \;`

Comment: It should be: `find -type f -name 'SystemOut.log.bz2' -execdir bzcat "62123456" {} \;`

Comment: Thanks hek2mgl. With your assistance, I finally got it working with the following command: `find . -type f -name 'SystemOut.log.bz2' -exec bzcat {} \; | grep -ia '3861449' | less`

Comment: Works. Is it possible to output the file name and maybe line as well?

Answer (score 5):

There are several methods:

```
bzgrep regexp $(find -name \*.bz2)
```

This method will work if number of the found files is not very big (and they have no special characters in the pathes). Otherwise you better use this one:

```
find -name \*.bz2 -exec bzgrep regexp {} /dev/null \;
```

Please note `/dev/null` in the second method. You use it to make `bzgrep` print the filename,
where the `regexp` was found.

Answer (score 5):

Just try to use:

```
bzgrep --help
grep through bzip2 files
```

Usage: `bzgrep [grep_options] pattern [files]`

For example, I need grep information from list of files by number 1941974:

```
'billing_log_1.bz'
'billing_log_2.bz'
'billing_log_3.bz'
'billing_log_4.bz'
'billing_log_5.bz'
```

What can I do?

`bzgrep '1941974' billing_log_1`

Comment: The question was how to grep recursively, `bzgrep` does not do it by default.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous your code with fixes by bzcat:

```
find . -type f -name "*.bz2" |while read file
do 
    bzcat $file | grep -ia 'text string' | less
done
```

Comment: Yes, you need save it in a bash file, such as a.sh, then give the execute permission by : chmod +x a.sh